# Function to change range input value not working

Tags: javascript

So, I have a input in my template

`<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" id="duration_slider" onchange="seek()">`

My javascript for seek() and updating the slider is

```
function seek(){
      slider_position = mysong.duration * (mysong.value / 100);
       mysong.currentTime = slider_position;
   }

function range_slider(){
    let position = 0;
        
        if(!isNaN(mysong.duration)){
           position = mysong.currentTime * (100 / mysong.duration);
           slider.value =  position;
          }      
     }
```

where `mysong` is the variable i get from my audio input in html.

```
var mysong = document.getElementById('mysong');
```

Sorry I don't know much javascript, I needed it while doing my django project. I applied same concept for my volume controls and it worked somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I hope value of your `slider_position` corresponding to value of `slider.value`.
So you need to catch that value from slider...

```
var slider = document.getElementById('duration_slider');
```

and than define value variable in `let slider_position` into `seek()` function

```
function seek() {
  let slider_position = slider.value;
  mysong.currentTime = slider_position;
  console.log(slider_position); //for displaying value in console
}
```

Comment: so the console is giving the right value but mysong.currentTime is 0 for some reasons

Comment: I don't know how you catch properties for " mysong ". Is your audio from HTML elements like <audio controls><src...></audio> or from input file where you later rendering file and receive parameters like duration..
But if you have simple object mysong = { duration: 4000, value: 0, currTime: 10} you can see in the console.log(mysong.currentTime) changed value.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type="range" id="slider" min="0" max="100" value="0"/>

    <script>
    var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
    const MAX_VALUE = 100;
    const MIN_VALUE = 1;
    function updateSliderRange(updatedValue){
        const currentValue = slider.value;
        slider.value = (currentValue >= MIN_VALUE && currentValue <=100) 
        ? updatedValue 
        : currentValue;
   }
   </script>
```